# can I increase root and other disk's size without formatting it

Tags: gparted, root, format

[image]want to shrink home ie sda5 and expand root ie sda3

```
Device        Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1      2048  20469759  20467712   9.8G Linux swap
/dev/sda2  20469760  28469247   7999488   3.8G BIOS boot
/dev/sda3  28469248  48939007  20469760   9.8G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda4  48939008  49133567    194560    95M EFI System
/dev/sda5  49133568 976771071 927637504 442.3G Linux filesystem
```

New partition

Device        Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1      2048  20469759  20467712   9.8G Linux swap
/dev/sda2  20469760  28469247   7999488   3.8G BIOS boot
/dev/sda3  28469248  79622143  51152896  24.4G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda4  79622144  80670719   1048576   512M EFI System
/dev/sda5  80670720 976773119 896102400 427.3G Linux filesystem

Comment: While you're in gparted, try cleaning up your partition order. You've got swap first? Typically partitioning should be boot, root, home then swap. The simplest method is often the best method.

Comment: @beertempest: How is your way "simplest"? Why is your partition order "the best method"? You're making stuff up.

Comment: It's not "my" partition order. It's the typical order for partitioning fresh installs. Do some research before you accuse people of something.

Comment: @beertempest I thought swap was usually after boot?

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen Swap is not being accessed as much as the root or home partitions during regular use so to speed read/write times up between root and home a bit it's better off last in the order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you *can* do this, but it's a little more complicated.

You MUST boot from some other medium (Live USB, Live CD, network boot from your local network, ...) and run `gparted`. `/dev/sda?` MUST NOT be mounted during this process.  You should have reliable power, and not be running on battery.

"Free Space" (which you will create by shrinking `/dev/sda5`) can only be added to adjacent partitions, so you will have to move partitions around.

All of this is from within `gparted`:

Select `/dev/sda5`.

`Menu->Partition->Move/Resize` will bring up a window like this[image: example of gparted resize/move]

When you set the new partition size, be sure to have all of your free space in `Free space preceeding`.

This will create Free space between `/dev/sda4` and `/dev/sda5`.

Select `/dev/sda4` and `Menu->Partition->Move/Resize`.

Then, move `/dev/sda4` to the other side of the "Free space" by clicking on the up-arrow in "Free space preceeding".

Finally, select `/dev/sda3`, `Menu->Partition->Move/Resize` and
adjust the "`New size`".

Examine the list of pending operations, double-checking for misexpressed intent. Fix as needed. When there's a match between what you want to do and what `gparted` is going to do, click the checkmark and stand back.

Comment: thanks. but after resizing i'm unable to boot i'm pasting new partition image plz help

Answer (score 1):

You sure can. Download [gparted](https://gparted.org/download.php).
Boot off that and you can resize the partitions. When your done resizing and have applied your changes, boot into your linux kernel. Gparted only resizes physical volumes, so you'll then have to resize the logical volume and the file system. See examples below.

- Extend the volume in LVS: `lvextend -l 100%FREE /dev/vg1/root`
- Resize Filesystem: `resize2fs /dev/sda5`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. You could boot your computer with a live medium that has a partition manager and use it to resize your partitions. Trying to do so after booting your system is usually not possible.

Comment: How... ? Please :)

Comment: https://gparted.org/liveusb.php